# Trouble With PHP Errors

Tags: php

I am working with  my website, and have just have completed it successfully.  This website is for payment process.  Everything works fine even though am getting errors.  What can I do to fix them?

Here are the errors:

```
Notice: Constant FIRSTNAME already defined in E:\wamp\www\david\include\variables.php on line 42

Notice: Constant LASTNAME already defined in E:\wamp\www\david\include\variables.php on line 43

Notice: Constant EMAIL already defined in E:\wamp\www\david\include\variables.php on line 44

Notice: Constant ADDRESS1 already defined in E:\wamp\www\david\include\variables.php on line 45

Notice: Constant ADDRESS2 already defined in E:\wamp\www\david\include\variables.php on line 46

Notice: Constant CITY already defined in E:\wamp\www\david\include\variables.php on line 47

Notice: Constant POSTCODE already defined in E:\wamp\www\david\include\variables.php on line 48
```

it comes untill the 63 lines..

How can I fix this?

Comment: And what cannot you understand from error description? The constants you want to define **have been already defined** earlier.

Comment: could you please post some code? otherwise it will be quite difficult to give you a relevant answer...

Answer (score 2):

Your are just including the file twice where these constants are defined.

Check and include them once.

if you are including the file use

```
require_once('constants.php')
```

instead of `include()`

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to re-define constants somewhere, an action that is not allowed (hence the name "constants").

My guess is that the same file is getting included more than once somewhere.  Look through your code to find out what file defines those constants, and then find out what places it's included.

You should also use `include_once` instead of `include`.  `include_once` checks to make sure it hasn't been included already.  See the manual here:

http://php.net/include-once

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are including the same thing twice in your .php page.

Answer (score -1):

you can turn off error reporting at run time using `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: You can sweep all your trash under the carpet.